# Parse.com: How to detect change in a relation field?

Tags: parse-platform

I have to detect changes in relation attributes of an object?

I have an object called Match with attribute pictures as a relation to Picture objects. Using Parse.Cloud.beforeSave, how can I detect a newly added Picture to this relation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From experimentation, you can get relation change details using:

```
request.operation.op(yourFieldName)
```

That returns a Parse.Op.Relation object.

Comment: Thank you! I actually found the answer some time ago.

Comment: Using Parse JS SDK v1.3.5 I got `Result: TypeError: Cannot call method 'op' of undefined`, I resolved it by using `request.object.op(yourFieldName)` instead

Answer (score 0):

The beforeSave trigger does not currently support the relation type (which is technically stored in a different collection.)

A suggestion for managing this would be to funnel changes to relations through a cloud function, where you can then perform additional logic.