# How to access changed relations in before safe

Tags: parse-platform, before-save

I would like to track some backend-changes in the cloud.

The log of my before_save tells me something like this:

```
before_save triggered for Elements for user oKwM9mvEUn:
  Input: {
  "original":
    {"elements":[
        {"__type":"Pointer","className":"Element","objectId":"VzeuG3Z5N6"},
        {"__type":"Pointer","className":"Element","objectId":"APkHJpgcms"},
        {"__type":"Pointer","className":"Element","objectId":"xHG1jg8fny"}
        ]},

    "update":
    {"elements":[
      {"__type":"Pointer","className":"Element","objectId":"VzeuG3Z5N6"},
      {"__type":"Pointer","className":"Element","objectId":"xHG1jg8fny"}
      ]}
    }

  Result: Update changed to 
  {"elements":[
  {"__type":"Pointer","className":"Element","objectId":"VzeuG3Z5N6"},
  {"__type":"Pointer","className":"Element","objectId":"xHG1jg8fny"}
  ]}
```

The dirtyKeys tells me that "elements" has been changed, but I would like to know what exactly has been added (or removed) because I only like to track the changes...

Is there a possibility to access those "update" values? Or do I have to track it by myself in an other property?

Thanks for a hint!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I posted on a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24647717/parse-com-how-to-detect-change-in-a-relation-field/28727122#28727122), you can get relation change details using:

```
request.operation.op(yourFieldName)
```

That returns a `Parse.Op.Relation` object.